# Margin при использовании FlexBox

Tags: css, flexbox

[image: Марджин**текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом**]

Откуда и почему у Всех элементов появился margin при использовании flexbox? И как его убрать

Comment: При чем тут `flex`? Это стандартные св-ва тегов по-умолчанию. У заголовков всех уровней `h1 ... h6` есть внешние отступы `margin`

Comment: сверху и снизу?

Comment: Да, http://prntscr.com/m1ezkf  `user agent stylesheet` это свойства тега по-умолчание такие какими их задумала разработчики. В данном случае и сверху и снизу margin у заголовка. Начните с введения в html css

Answer (score 1):

Все работает. Нужно было не ставить justify-content